# Is Visual Studio 2008 a 32Bit Application?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, virtual-memory

Is the Visual Studio Application 32Bit , and thus can only address max 4GB ram?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio is 32bit. To produce 64-bit code of your program it uses cross compiler (but there is already Beta 2 version of 64-bit tools).

It could use 3Gb of virtual memory on 32-bit OS (when OS loaded with [`increaseuserva`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906211.aspx) switch or `/3GB` switch on WinXP), and 4Gb of virtual memory on 64-bit OS. It was built with `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag. You could check it by using [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) utility with `/HEADERS` switch. To get more information on virtual memory limits you could read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) article by Mark Russinovich.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is still 32-bit. Rico Mariani has an [explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx) of why.

Answer (score 3):

As said above, Visual studio is 32-bit application. That's why IDE can use only 2BG of virtual memory. But exists solution that allows your VS use more memory. In [this article](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx) explains how you can do that.

Comment: VS already built with LARGEADDRESSAWARE. No need to edit it.

Comment: This would have possibly been a concern on VS 2005 or even 2003, but the question is for VS2008

Comment: Actually running under 64 bit operating systems 32 bit applications can now address up to 4 GB.